# When is the matrix of eigenvectors of a complex symmetric matrix orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a complex symmetric matrix $A=A^\top$ with a matrix of eigenvectors $C$ (which have distinct non zero eigenvalues) it can be shown that $C^\top C=I$ and that $C^\top A C=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues.

I want to know how to show that further to the above $C^\top C= C C^\top =I$. And if this is not always true when it will be true.

Comment: why don't you orthonormalize the eigen vectors??

Comment: I really doubt, that your statement ist true, because finding such a Matrix $C$ such that $C^T C=I$ is equivalent to being normal. But every normal matrix is diagonalizable but complex symmetric matrices aren't diagonalizable in general

Comment: I think that if $C$ and $A$ have inverses then the above must be true since: $D^2=C^\top A^2 C= C^\top A C C^\top A C$

Comment: this is true as soon as the eigenvalues are simple.

Comment: Thanks mookid, do you have a proof or reference?

Comment: If $C^T C= I$ then $C^T $ is the inverse of $C$ and those commute. hence $C C^T=I$ too

Comment: @Joe [FYI](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i). Also, could you provide (at least) a reference on the fact you claim to be true?

Comment: Thanks yes see my reply to the first answer. (please let me know if I have done something very silly)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the condition that $C^\top C=I$ it follows that since $C$ is a square matrix $C C^\top=I$ see:

[If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/50606)

Comment: (I'm new to stackexchange so if someone with experience would tell me if I should just delete this question that would be helpful)